# NuSMV getting stuck on pick_state command

Tags: nusmv, sat-solvers

I'm making a model of a graph where messages are being routed over channels between nodes for a homework assignment.

(Basically, the messages only contain the id of the destination node, nodes can create messages and route them by a predefined routing table, each channel can contain one message at a time and the goal is to find deadlocks.)

The problem is after adding about 10 nodes (I need 14) NuSMV gets stuck on selecting a initial state even though all channels should just be 0. I'm not sure why it gets stuck (with 10 nodes the pick_state takes a few seconds and simulation is pretty much instant). Could there be some environment variables I should change or is there some problem in my model?

Here is the code (I'm still a beginner):

```
-- Gives next channel id for node i and msg destination j
MODULE route(i,j)
DEFINE
    -- out '0' implies no route
    out := 
        case
        j = 0 : 0; -- empty message
        i = j : 0; -- already at destination
        i = 1 : 1;
        i = 2 : 2;
        i = 3 : 
            case
            j in {1,2,12,13,14} : 6;
            TRUE : 3;
            esac;
        i = 4 : 
            case
            j in {1,2,12,13,14} : 21;
            j in {3,5} : 4;
            TRUE : 7;
            esac;
        i = 5 : 5;
        i = 6 : 8;
        i = 7 : 9;
        i = 8 : 
            case
            j in {1,2,12,13,14} : 17;
            j in {3,4,5,6,7} : 20;
            TRUE : 10;
            esac;
        i = 9 : 11;
        i = 10 : 12;
        i = 11 : 13;
        i = 12 : 
            case
            j = 13 : 14;
            j = 14 : 18;
            TRUE : 16;
            esac;
        i = 13 : 15;
        i = 14 : 19;
        TRUE : 0;
        esac;

-- Node with id, at most 4 in and 3 out channels with known ids
-- also a new 'channel' for creating new msgs
MODULE node(id, new, in1, in2, in3, in4, out1, out2, out3, out1_id, out2_id, out3_id)
    VAR
        r  : route(id,new); -- route for new msg
        r1 : route(id,in1); -- route for msg on channel 1
        r2 : route(id,in2); -- route for msg on channel 2
        r3 : route(id,in3); -- ...
        r4 : route(id,in4);
    TRANS
    -- out occupied or (free and (  stay free    or     pull from input channel if route matches       ))
        (out1 != 0 | (out1 = 0 & (next(out1) = 0 | (r1.out = out1_id & next(out1) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)
                                                 | (r2.out = out1_id & next(out1) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)
                                                 | (r3.out = out1_id & next(out1) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)
                                                 | (r4.out = out1_id & next(out1) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)
                                                 | (r.out  = out1_id & next(out1) = new & next(new) = 0)))) &
        (out2 != 0 | (out2 = 0 & (next(out2) = 0 | (r1.out = out2_id & next(out2) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)
                                                 | (r2.out = out2_id & next(out2) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)
                                                 | (r3.out = out2_id & next(out2) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)
                                                 | (r4.out = out2_id & next(out2) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)
                                                 | (r.out  = out2_id & next(out2) = new & next(new) = 0)))) &
        (out3 != 0 | (out3 = 0 & (next(out3) = 0 | (r1.out = out3_id & next(out3) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)
                                                 | (r2.out = out3_id & next(out3) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)
                                                 | (r3.out = out3_id & next(out3) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)
                                                 | (r4.out = out3_id & next(out3) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)
                                                 | (r.out  = out3_id & next(out3) = new & next(new) = 0)))) &
    -- in empty or (   msg at destination    or ( msg should be routed and (wait or push to out channel by route )))
        (in1 = 0 | (in1 = id & next(in1) = 0) | (in1 != id & in1 != 0 & (next(in1) = in1
                                              | (r1.out = out1_id & out1 = 0 & next(out1) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)
                                              | (r1.out = out2_id & out2 = 0 & next(out2) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)
                                              | (r1.out = out3_id & out3 = 0 & next(out3) = in1 & next(in1) = 0)))) &
        (in2 = 0 | (in2 = id & next(in2) = 0) | (in2 != id & in2 != 0 & (next(in2) = in2
                                              | (r2.out = out1_id & out1 = 0 & next(out1) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)
                                              | (r2.out = out2_id & out2 = 0 & next(out2) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)
                                              | (r2.out = out3_id & out3 = 0 & next(out3) = in2 & next(in2) = 0)))) &
        (in3 = 0 | (in3 = id & next(in3) = 0) | (in3 != id & in3 != 0 & (next(in3) = in3
                                              | (r3.out = out1_id & out1 = 0 & next(out1) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)
                                              | (r3.out = out2_id & out2 = 0 & next(out2) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)
                                              | (r3.out = out3_id & out3 = 0 & next(out3) = in3 & next(in3) = 0)))) &
        (in4 = 0 | (in4 = id & next(in3) = 0) | (in4 != id & in4 != 0 & (next(in4) = in4
                                              | (r4.out = out1_id & out1 = 0 & next(out1) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)
                                              | (r4.out = out2_id & out2 = 0 & next(out2) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)
                                              | (r4.out = out3_id & out3 = 0 & next(out3) = in4 & next(in4) = 0)))) &
        (new = 0 | (new = id & next(new) = 0) | (new != id & new != 0 & (next(new) = new
                                              | (r.out  = out1_id & out1 = 0 & next(out1) = new & next(new) = 0)
                                              | (r.out  = out2_id & out2 = 0 & next(out2) = new & next(new) = 0)
                                              | (r.out  = out3_id & out3 = 0 & next(out3) = new & next(new) = 0))))

MODULE main
    DEFINE
        M := {1,3,11};
    VAR
        c1  : 0..14;
        c2  : 0..14;
        c3  : 0..14;
        c4  : 0..14;
        c5  : 0..14;
        c6  : 0..14;
        c7  : 0..14;
        c8  : 0..14;
        c9  : 0..14;
        c10 : 0..14;
        c11 : 0..14;
        c12 : 0..14;
        c13 : 0..14;
        c14 : 0..14;
        c15 : 0..14;
        c16 : 0..14;
        c17 : 0..14;
        c18 : 0..14;
        c19 : 0..14;
        c20 : 0..14;
        c21 : 0..14;
        new1  : 0..14;
        new2  : 0..14;
        new3  : 0..14;
        new4  : 0..14;
        new5  : 0..14;
        new6  : 0..14;
        new7  : 0..14;
        new8  : 0..14;
        new9  : 0..14;
        new10 : 0..14;
        new11 : 0..14;
        new12 : 0..14;
        new13 : 0..14;
        new14 : 0..14;
    -- NODE        ID, NEW  , IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4, OUT1 OUT2 OUT3 [ OUT IDS ]
        n1  : node(1 , new1 , c16, 0  , 0  , 0  , c1 , 0  , 0  , 1 , 0 , 0 );
        n2  : node(2 , new2 , c1 , 0  , 0  , 0  , c2 , 0  , 0  , 2 , 0 , 0 );
        n3  : node(3 , new3 , c2 , c5 , 0  , 0  , c3 , c6 , 0  , 3 , 6 , 0 );
        n4  : node(4 , new4 , c3 , c20, 0  , 0  , c4 , c7 , c21, 4 , 7 , 21);
        n5  : node(5 , new5 , c4 , 0  , 0  , 0  , c5 , 0  , 0  , 5 , 0 , 0 );
        n6  : node(6 , new6 , c7 , 0  , 0  , 0  , c8 , 0  , 0  , 8 , 0 , 0 );
        n7  : node(7 , new7 , c8 , 0  , 0  , 0  , c9 , 0  , 0  , 9 , 0 , 0 );
        n8  : node(8 , new8 , c9 , 0  , 0  , 0  , c10, c17, c20, 10, 17, 20);
        n9  : node(9 , new9 , c10, 0  , 0  , 0  , c11, 0  , 0  , 11, 0 , 0 );
        n10 : node(10, new10, c11, 0  , 0  , 0  , c12, 0  , 0  , 12, 0 , 0 );
        n11 : node(11, new11, c12, 0  , 0  , 0  , c13, 0  , 0  , 13, 0 , 0 );
        n12 : node(12, new12, c13, c15, c19, 0  , c14, c16, c18, 14, 16, 18);
        n13 : node(13, new13, c14, 0  , 0  , 0  , c15, 0  , 0  , 15, 0 , 0 );
        n14 : node(14, new14, c6 , c17, c18, c21, c19, 0  , 0  , 19, 0 , 0 );
    INIT
        c1  = 0 &
        c2  = 0 &
        c3  = 0 &
        c4  = 0 &
        c5  = 0 &
        c6  = 0 &
        c7  = 0 &
        c8  = 0 &
        c9  = 0 &
        c10 = 0 &
        c11 = 0 &
        c12 = 0 &
        c13 = 0 &
        c14 = 0 &
        c15 = 0 &
        c16 = 0 &
        c17 = 0 &
        c18 = 0 &
        c19 = 0 &
        c20 = 0 &
        c21 = 0 &
        new1  = 0 &
        new2  = 0 &
        new3  = 0 &
        new4  = 0 &
        new5  = 0 &
        new6  = 0 &
        new7  = 0 &
        new8  = 0 &
        new9  = 0 &
        new10 = 0 &
        new11 = 0 &
        new12 = 0 &
        new13 = 0 &
        new14 = 0 
    TRANS
        (next(new1 ) = 0 | (1  in M & next(new1 ) in M)) &
        (next(new2 ) = 0 | (2  in M & next(new2 ) in M)) &
        (next(new3 ) = 0 | (3  in M & next(new3 ) in M)) &
        (next(new4 ) = 0 | (4  in M & next(new4 ) in M)) &
        (next(new5 ) = 0 | (5  in M & next(new5 ) in M)) &
        (next(new6 ) = 0 | (6  in M & next(new6 ) in M)) &
        (next(new7 ) = 0 | (7  in M & next(new7 ) in M)) &
        (next(new8 ) = 0 | (8  in M & next(new8 ) in M)) &
        (next(new9 ) = 0 | (9  in M & next(new9 ) in M)) &
        (next(new10) = 0 | (10 in M & next(new10) in M)) &
        (next(new11) = 0 | (11 in M & next(new11) in M)) &
        (next(new12) = 0 | (12 in M & next(new12) in M)) &
        (next(new13) = 0 | (13 in M & next(new13) in M)) &
        (next(new14) = 0 | (14 in M & next(new14) in M))
```

[Image of the graph with labeled ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bviQw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `go_bmc` and `bmc_pick_state` instead of `go` and `pick_state`.

If instead you need to use OBDDs for some reason, then you could specify the option `-dynamic` to NuSMV and enable the dynamic reordering of variables.

On my machine the selection of the initial state for your model becomes much faster in both cases.